Objects don't show up in render, render button greyed out
I'm pretty much a newbie with Blender, but have set up a few scenes before. Now I have been working on a scene and my renders with cycles turned out ok so far. But then I must have pressed some button and don't know which one, so that about the half of my objects don't show up in the render anymore, although they show up in the viewport and are selected for render. Their render symbol is greyed out, as shown in the picture. What did I do? I'm using Blender 4.0.2 on an Intel Mac.

Thanks!

Turns out I have accidentally disabled the whole collection. Problem solved.
